# Windows 10 Multi-App Kiosk Mode: Preventing Unauthorized Browser Access and Kiosk Mode Escape Exploits

Tags: windows, windows-10, kiosk-mode, kiosk

I've set up a Windows 10 Multi-App Kiosk Mode for a specific application in my organization and didn't allow Microsoft Edge in the allowed application list. The kiosk mode itself is functioning as expected with no apparent issues.

However, I've noticed that when users click on hyperlinks within the allowed application, it opens Microsoft Edge, potentially allowing them to break out of the kiosk mode using certain exploits.

I'm looking for advice on how to mitigate this security risk. Are there any specific configurations or settings that I can apply to prevent unauthorized browser access and kiosk mode escape exploits while still allowing users to interact with hyperlinks within the application?

Any help or insights into securing the Windows 10 Multi-App Kiosk Mode in this context would be greatly appreciated.

Checked the xml configuration to see if edge is enabled but its not.